# How to detect Mail:failures with Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-mail

I am sending users an email based on form data. After looking at the docs for [Mail](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/mail#sending-mail), I figured out how to send an email. However, let's say the user made a typo in their input, how can I display to the user that their email bounced?

Here is my code that does not work

```
if( count(Mail::failures()) > 0 ) {
    echo "There was one or more failures. They were: <br />";
    foreach(Mail::failures as $email_address) {
        echo " - $email_address <br />";
    }
} else {
    echo "No errors, all sent successfully!";
}
```

"Not work" means that I can write in a random email such as `dfgkndgrigpergerg@fioerjoif.com` and it will say `"No errors, all sent successfully!"`

Comment: Same question. When we sending bulk emails, maybe some of them not sent properly, because as you mentioned before, some of emails are not valid like `dfgkndgrigpergerg@fioerjoif.com`, or maybe because internet is disconnected, so they are not sent. I use this way as well to identify all unsent emails, but still failed. Did you got a solution to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is you can't verify this in Laravel.

You provide a from address in your laravel configuration, and if you send an email from this address to an address that doesn't exist, it will still be sent to your smtp-service and to the receiving server which holds the address domain name. In some cases you will be returned an non-recipient answer from that server, and in some cases you will not. This is not depending on wheiter you send the email from Laravel or from another mail client app.

If you want to prevent the users from doing type-o's, you should instead consider adding a verification field and make the user re-type the email address and validate them with the _confirmation validation rule in Laravel. (https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#rule-confirmed)

Comment: Ok I got it. But I have a kind of another curiosity. Assume for example an email address is valid, but it's not sent properly because an internet disconnected. Is laravel can give a warning about it?

Comment: @SeadLab I can't tell if you're serious or not?

Answer (score 1):

I thought that is not possible, but after a searching i found this:

https://github.com/hbattat/verifyEmail

> Is a PHP function that can be easily used to verify an email address and make sure it is valid and does exist on the mail server.
>
> This function connects to the mail server and checks whether the mailbox exists or not.

Simply call the function:

```
verifyEmail('some.email.address@example.com', 'my.email.address@my-domain.com');
```

> The first email address 'some.email.address@example.com' is the one to be checked, and the second 'my.email.address@my-domain.com' is an email address to be provided to the server (just for testing, but would be better if it is a valid email)
>
> This will restun a string "valid" if the email some.email.address@example.com is valid, and "invalid" if the email is invalid

Hope it helps!

Comment: I have rewritten this code, and now it is a class and can be installed via composer. check out the latest version. Thanks

Comment: Ok I got it. But I have a kind of another curiosity. Assume for example an email address is valid, but it's not sent properly because an internet disconnected. Is laravel can give a warning about it?

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add that you should never trust Mail::failures(), as it will return errors only in very specific cases, which is almost never. For example, SMTP might return a failure immediately, but sendmail almost never does. Mail:failures() might be suitable for handling unexpected sender errors (failure to authenticate or something similar), but not for verification.

So yeah, most of the time you can only find out if the address was correct after sending email to it.