# Get failed email ids on sending bulk email - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

I want to send emails to 100 users but the requirement is I want a list of successful and failed email ids.
I can achieve this by for loop but It is taking time for execution.

I also tried the below code to send bulk emails.

```
  $subject = "Test Email";
  $email_to = ['dhaval@test','yasin@yopmail.com'];

  $result = Mail::send([], [], function ($message) use($email_to ,$subject){
      $message->to($email_to)
        ->subject($subject);
    });
    
  dd( Mail:: failures()); // return empty array

  dd($result); // return empty array
```

By sending this way, a function is not returning any failed emails list.

So my question is how to get list of successful/failed email ids in bulk sending Or Is there any alternate way to send bulk emails and get both list.

Comment: Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37679777/how-to-detect-mailfailures-with-laravel-5-2

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/32048151/7729405

Comment: @AqibJaved, I checked link, but this is not answer to my question, that answer is about to check email id, but what if email is proper but mail server not able to send emil

Comment: @TimurRodya, I am doing same now :) using for loop but it takes execution time

Answer (score -1):

use it

```
$subject = "Test Email";
$emails = ['dhaval@test','yasin@yopmail.com'];
foreach($emails as $email_to){
    $result = Mail::send([], [], function ($message) use($email_to ,$subject){
        $message->to($email_to)->subject($subject);
    });
}
```

Comment: Read the question and comments properly before answer